# Where is the Groovy documentation?

Tags: installation, documentation

I have installed the Groovy documentation from the Ubuntu Software Centre, but where does it reside? And how to view it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) standards documentation files are usually installed in `/usr/share/doc`.

For groovy you will find these files in `/usr/share/doc/groovy-doc`. The documentation can be viewed in any browser by opening

`file:///usr/share/doc/groovy-doc/groovy-jdk/index.html`